# Summation Over Lines in a File (Advent of Code 2018 Day 1)

Tags: beginner, rust, iterator

*Preface: I am learning Rust through the Advent of Code*

The task is to read lines from a file, parse each as an integer, then provide a summation of all the numbers. My solution looks like this:

```rust
use std::fs::File;
use std::io::{self, prelude::*, BufReader};

fn main() -> io::Result<()> {
    let file = File::open("day01.txt")?;
    let reader = BufReader::new(file);

    let mut sum: i32 = 0;

    for line in reader.lines() {
      let value: i32 = line.unwrap().parse().unwrap();
      sum += value
    }

    println!("{}", sum);

    Ok(())
}
```

I'd like to use the iterator methods `map` and `sum` in my solution, but I haven't figured out how to do so with the type checker. Suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's how you use `Iterator::sum`:

```
use std::fs::File;
use std::io::{self, prelude::*, BufReader};

fn main() -> io::Result<()> {
    let file = File::open("day01.txt")?;
    let reader = BufReader::new(file);
    let sum: i32 = reader
        .lines()
        .map(|line| line.unwrap().parse::<i32>().unwrap())
        .sum();

    println!("{}", sum);

    Ok(())
}
```

You must first say to what type the line must be parsed: `parse::<i32>()` and then, you must give the sum a type because the output of the `Add` trait is not the same as `self` and `other`.